# symfony's propel admin generator error

Tags: symfony1, propel, admin-generator

i'm working on a symfony project based on an existing mysql database, and i generated the shcema.yml from it.The first app created is the backend.
But when i try to add a module with the command

```
$ php symfony propel:generate-admin backend <ClassName> --module=<classname>
```

so when i try to access to the url of this backend module (http://localhost/project/web/backend_dev.php/<'classname>) throws me this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Base<'ClassName>GeneratorConfiguration' not found in .../www/proeject/apps/backend/modules/<'classname>/lib/<'classname>GeneratorConfiguration.class.php on line 12

i've searched in other projects (the jobeet tutorial, for example) and in this file there are no classes defined.

### Edit:

I think the error is because symfony can't find the class `Base<ClassName>GeneratorConfiguration`, parent class of `<ClassName>GeneratorConfiguration`. So i think the problem is that i have not located this class properly in the project. Do you know if i must apply some plugin or call some task from commandline to solve this?

### /Edit

Do you have any idea of what is happening? Maybe i've forget to declare something before generate the backend modules...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIx'd: This was because i'm using a remote editing to test the project on a different machine. So when i generated the admin module, some caché files were created, such as `Base<ClassName>GeneratorConfiguration`, but the remote syncoronizer i use, as the local caché folder had no those generated files, erased them from the remote folder.